# Use google docs in asp.net application

Tags: google-docs

How can I use GOOGLE DOCS in my project which I am doing using asp.net with C# as code behind.

Basically I need to display some pdf, doc,dox,excel documents in a read only form in the browser.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google docs has an API for that.

> The Google Documents List Data API allows client applications to programmatically access 
>   and manipulate user data stored with Google Documents.

Check it's [documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/documents/overview.html), it has examples and everything you would need to develop something based on google docs.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;  
using System.IO;  
using System.Net;  
using Google.Documents;  
using Google.GData.Client;  

namespace Google  
{  
    class Program  
    {  
        private static string applicationName = "Testing";  

        static void Main(string[] args)  
        {  
            GDataCredentials credentials = new GDataCredentials("username@gmail.com", "password");  
            RequestSettings settings = new RequestSettings(applicationName, credentials);  
            settings.AutoPaging = true;  
            settings.PageSize = 100;  
            DocumentsRequest documentsRequest = new DocumentsRequest(settings);  
            Feed<document> documentFeed = documentsRequest.GetDocuments();  
            foreach (Document document in documentFeed.Entries)  
            {  
                Document.DownloadType type = Document.DownloadType.pdf;  

                Stream downloadStream = documentsRequest.Download(document, type);  

                Stream fileSaveStream = new FileStream(string.Format(@"C:\Temp\{0}.pdf", document.Title), FileMode.CreateNew);  

                if (fileSaveStream != null)  
                {  
                    int nBytes = 2048;  
                    int count = 0;  
                    Byte[] arr = new Byte[nBytes];  

                    do  
                    {  
                        count = downloadStream.Read(arr, 0, nBytes);  
                        fileSaveStream.Write(arr, 0, count);  

                    } while (count > 0);  
                    fileSaveStream.Flush();  
                    fileSaveStream.Close();  
                }  
                downloadStream.Close();  
            }  

        }  
    }  
}
```