# Do we need a google account to use google docs in a web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How i can use google docs to view uploaded files (.doc,.txt,.pdf,.xls) in my web Application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566239/use-google-docs-in-asp-net-application

Comment: http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/documents/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the viewer in an `iframe` :

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.example.com/path/to/file.pdf&embedded=true" frameborder="1" style="width: 700px;height: 920px;">
    <noframes>
        Y U NO support iframes?
    </noframes>
</iframe>
```

You'll find [here](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1189935) a list of the [supported file types](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1189935). As of now :

> Google Docs supports over 15 different file types, listed below:
>
> - Microsoft Word (.DOC and .DOCX)
> - Microsoft Excel (.XLS and .XLSX)
> - Microsoft PowerPoint (.PPT and .PPTX)
> - Adobe Portable Document Format (.PDF)
> - Apple Pages (.PAGES)
> - Adobe Illustrator (.AI)
> - Adobe Photoshop (.PSD)
> - Tagged Image File Format (.TIFF)
> - Autodesk AutoCad (.DXF)
> - Scalable Vector Graphics (.SVG)
> - PostScript (.EPS, .PS)
> - TrueType (.TTF)
> - XML Paper Specification (.XPS)
> - Archive file types (.ZIP and .RAR)

If you need more than just viewing, do as the other answers suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [Google Documents API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/documents/), and yes you'll need a Google Account in order to work with the API. How else could you identify which files to list?

Actually, upon further thought the answer to your question about whether or not you need a Google Account is "maybe." It really depends on your requirements. If you want to write an application that lists and manipulates other people's files then no, you don't really need to have a Google account for the purposes of development. You use oAuth to login to the user's account.

However, in order to get a API key you do have to have a Google account, but that's the extent of what you'll need your own Google account for.