# Getting textbox value from one page to another page textbox value

Tags: asp.net, html, forms

I am creating a form in my website and i link this form to the google docs (FORM which i created there). But this new form that i am trying to do is this in such a way that a textbox value from the first page should be passed over to the next page lets say page2 textbox value

CODE IS ROUGHLY SOMETHING LIKE THIS 
PAGE 1.html,aspx,asp (Watever)
"/>

Page2.html,aspx,asp (Watever)
 **readonly**"/>

So since i am using the google docs to save my data
 
          **
form action="http://docs.google.com 
i am unsure how to pass these values, tks for the help.

Presently i am just getting the values from page1 to page2 using this microsoft tutorial
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300104

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to read

[How to: Pass Values Between ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx)

you can store values using the approaches listed there.

Eg:

On your Page 1:

Create a textbox named  textbox  and an asp button.

on button.click code behind add

```
Session["test"] = textbox.Text;
Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx"); //Open page 2
```

On your Page 2 :

Creata a label named label1

Then on its Pageload Event in code behind

Add

```
string IpassAstringfrompage1 = Convert.ToString(Session["test"]);

label1.Text = IpassAstringfrompage1; //label1 will display TESTING from textbox on Page1
```

To test. On Page1 input "TESTING" on your textbox then click button

Regards

Comment: hi manm this equally confusing can you kindly show me a simple code. Like the page1 wat code i need to type, it must have a textbox and in the page2 another textbox but with its value being the page1 textbox value..tks so much for the effort.

Comment: Possible to do this with just html and javascript? Cause as i mentioned i am storing my data in google docs, so there might be inconsistencies rising up tks

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566239/use-google-docs-in-asp-net-application

Comment: haha that is totally unrelated but its ok i found an answer thru the best search engine site google at this link this is easy http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471111/A-Quick-Tutorial-on-JavaScript-Variable-Passing.htm

Comment: i also find that link also... : ) That's simple.